# Who came up with "suck, squeeze, bang, blow"?

Tags: engine, four-stroke, history

A popular explanation of how a four stroke engine works is

> Suck, squeeze, bang, blow.

The engine *sucks* in a mixture of fuel and air, then *squeezes* it together (compresses it), then it burns / explodes that with a *bang*, and finally it *blows* out the exhaust.

But who came up with this very simple explanation first?

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but I did. :o) Realistically, I wouldn't have a clue, but I use it to describe a four cycle engine regularly and agree it is a very simple and easily understood explanation.

Comment: I don't know, but I'd recommend that you be very careful when searching for it on the internet....

Comment: @Pete  Yeah, I was thankful I work mostly from home when I googled that.

Comment: My ex-wife prior to the divorce proceedings ....Lets not go there..LOL :)-

Comment: I learned it as Suck Squeeze Pop Phooey, which I gotta say, I like better. It's more charmning, and has less sexual connotations.

Comment: It should really be Suck, Squeeze, (controlled) Burn, Blow... as it is not an explosion in the cylinder...

Answer (score 12):

This phrase has been around very long and has been used in the aviation industry as well as automobile.  This is a very good, and more importantly, very easy for anyone to understand way of describing the four cycles of the engine.

Here is an excerpt from an [Aviation safety report](https://books.google.com/books?id=lqDVAAAAMAAJ&q=suck+squeeze+bang+blow&dq=suck+squeeze+bang+blow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjowKzbqKDMAhXHSyYKHSNpBWk4FBDoAQgkMAA) from 1958:

[image]

*Air Safety Forum: Reports Presented at the Annual Air Safety Forum of the Air Line Pilots Association*

If this was so widely used as to make it into a safety report for the Airline Association in 1958, it must have been in common usage well before that.

I would venture to say the phrase or a similar phrase probably appeared as cars were becoming a household item and mechanics had a need to start explaining how things worked.

Actually, I wouldn't be surprised if the great [Nikolaus August Otto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolaus_Otto), inventor of the four-cycle engine had a similar saying to explain his engine: *Saugen,  Drücken, Knall, Schlag*...